# Calling java timer in a synchronized block of codes

Tags: java, timer, synchronized-block

If I have a parent block of codes called A, A is synchronized. And in A, I executes a child block of code called B. Am I right to assume that B will be synchronized also?

If in A I have a timer to delay the execution of B in a certain of t time, is there a chance that B gets executed later when A already finished?

Thank you very much.

P/S: Sorry the the unclear code, this is how it should look like

```
   synchronized  A{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        B block
      }
    }, 2*60*1000);

    }
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you mean. Can you illustrate your question with some code?

Comment: I think Block `B` would also be synchronous. I believe, in java, all code is executed synchronously by default. If `B` is contained in `A`, and `A` and `B` are executed synchronously, then `A` will not finish until after `B` finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends.  If the block B is a block of code within method like this, then yes...  it will be synchronized.

```
public synchronized void methodA() {
    // Block B
    {
       // some code
    }
}
```

If it's another method like the following, then no:

```
public synchronized void methodA() {
    methodB();
}

public void methodB() {
    // Block B code
    // Nothing prevents an unsynchronized method from calling this method
    //   at same time as methodA() holds  lock on `this` object
}
```

Unless `methodB` is also marked `synchronized` *or* called from another synchronized method (eg/ `public synchronized methodC()`) *or* another synchronization mechanism is used, then `methodB()` is not synchronized.

Those are just the simplest cases.  You're better off posting example code since 'block' is not well defined by default and the type of synchronization lock (implicit on `this` via synchronized method vs. explicit object lock) makes a difference.

But, your last line sounds like you're asking about synchronous vs. asynchronous execution of code which, while related to threading and `synchronized` blocks, is a different concept.

In that case, it depends on what happens in `block A` ... if new threads are created to execute `block B` then anything can happen with the timing of code execution.  If no threads are created, it's safe to assume that `block A` will not complete before `block B`.

Edit: based on code now posted ... the synchronized `A block` will only ensure the Timer threads get created one at a time.  But, unless there's something special about the Java `Timer` framework, there's nothing there that will prevent two threads from executing the `B block` in the `run` method simultaneously ... so make sure that the contents are thread safe.

That is, don't assume that just because different instances of `Timer` are created in a synchronized block with the same delay, they won't get into the run method at the same time.  If the `B block` accesses external un-thread-safe code (eg. static methods, disk access), you could have surprises.

As Amm Sokun mentioned in other answer, `A{}` will return before 
`Block B` executes.

Answer (score 1):

Block B will be executed after A has finished executing, this is because in method A you are just scheduling B to be run after `2*60*1000` milli, and timer will take care of executing B after `2*60*1000` milli